# how to get current/Todays date data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, current-time

how to write query to get today's date data in `SQL server` ?

```
select * from tbl_name where date = <Todays_date>
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The correct answer will depend on the type of your `datecolumn`. Assuming it is of type `Date`:

```
select * from tbl_name 
where datecolumn = cast(getdate() as Date)
```

If it is `DateTime`:

```
select * from tbl_name 
where cast(datecolumn as Date) = cast(getdate() as Date)
```

**Please note**: In SQL Server, a `datediff()` (or other calculation) on a column is NOT Sargable, whereas as `CAST(column AS Date)` is.

Answer (score 6):

<strike>Seems Mitch Wheat's answer isn't [sargable](http://blog.sqlthoughts.com/2014/03/13/what-makes-a-query-sargable/), although I am not sure this is true.</strike>

Please note: a `DATEDIFF()` (or other calculation) on LHS is NOT Sargable, whereas as `Cast(x to Date)` is.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_name 
WHERE date >= cast(getdate() as date)
and date < cast(getdate()+1 as date)
```

Comment: actually, later versions of sql server (2K8)+ appear to be  'cast-to-date' s-argable aware. I use to think this would preclude the use of an index and then I tested it.

Comment: @MitchWheat I am glad to hear that. I had my doubts and started browsing. As you can tell from my link it was written last year. The author doesn't mention which version he is using though

Comment: Please note: a datediff() (or other calculation) on LHS is NOT Sargable, whereas as Cast(x to Date) is.

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from tbl_name where date = cast(getdate() as Date)
```

for `CAST` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx and for `GETDATE()` see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188383.aspx